# Capturing volume levels with AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, audiobuffer

I'm trying to live volume levels using AVCaptureDevice etc it compiles and runs but the values just seem to be random and I keep getting overflow errors as well.

**EDIT:**

also is it normal for the RMS range to be 0 to about 20000?

```
        if let audioCaptureDevice : AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio){



            try audioCaptureDevice.lockForConfiguration()

            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioCaptureDevice)
            audioCaptureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()

            if(captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput)){
                captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
                print("added input")
            }


            let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()

            audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: GlobalUserInitiatedQueue)

            if(captureSession.canAddOutput(audioOutput)){
                captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput)
                print("added output")
            }


            //supposed to start session not on UI queue coz it takes a while
            dispatch_async(GlobalUserInitiatedQueue) {
                print("starting captureSession")
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        }
```

...

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, let didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    // Needs to be initialized somehow, even if we take only the address
    var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList(mNumberBuffers: 1,
        mBuffers: AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 1, mDataByteSize: 0, mData: nil))
    //this needs to be in method otherwise only runs 125 times?
    var blockBuffer: CMBlockBuffer?

    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
        sampleBuffer,
        nil,
        &audioBufferList,
        sizeof(audioBufferList.dynamicType),
        nil,
        nil,
        UInt32(kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment),
        &buffer
    )



    let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(&audioBufferList)

    for buffer in abl{
        let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start: UnsafeMutablePointer(buffer.mData),
            count: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)/sizeof(Int16))


        var sum:Int = 0
        for sample in samples {
            sum = sum + Int(sample*sample)

        }

        let rms = sqrt(Double(sum)/count)
    }
```

Comment: I'm not to play with audio buffers and stuff, nontheless I'd like to get an average audio level like you, could you explain in more details what's happenning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears I have it working. I casted `sample` to an `Int64` before doing any manipulations.

```
        for buffer in abl{
        let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start: UnsafeMutablePointer(buffer.mData),
            count: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)/sizeof(Int16))

        var sum:Int64 = 0

        for sample in samples {
         let s = Int64(sample)
         sum +=s*s
        }


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.volLevel.text = String(sqrt(Float(sum/Int64(samples.count))))
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`'s method

```
captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, let didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

to get `AVCaptureConnection` from last parameter.

Then get `AVCaptureAudioChannel` from `connection.audioChannels`

Then you can get volume levels from it:

```
audioChannel.averagePowerLevel
audioChannel.peakHoldLevel
```

Answer (score 6):

Hey I don't understand much of it but here is a working Swift 5 version:

```swift
func captureOutput(_            output      : AVCaptureOutput,
                   didOutput    sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                   from         connection  : AVCaptureConnection) {

    var buffer: CMBlockBuffer? = nil

    // Needs to be initialized somehow, even if we take only the address
    let convenianceBuffer = AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 1, mDataByteSize: 0, mData: nil)
    var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList(mNumberBuffers: 1,
                                          mBuffers: convenianceBuffer)

    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
        sampleBuffer,
        bufferListSizeNeededOut: nil,
        bufferListOut: &audioBufferList,
        bufferListSize: MemoryLayout<AudioBufferList>.size(ofValue: audioBufferList),
        blockBufferAllocator: nil,
        blockBufferMemoryAllocator: nil,
        flags: UInt32(kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment),
        blockBufferOut: &buffer
    )

    let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(&audioBufferList)

    for buffer in abl {
        let originRawPtr = buffer.mData
        let ptrDataSize = Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)

        // From raw pointer to typed Int16 pointer
        let buffPtrInt16 = originRawPtr?.bindMemory(to: Int16.self, capacity: ptrDataSize)

        // From pointer typed Int16 to pointer of [Int16]
        // So we can iterate on it simply
        let unsafePtrByteSize = ptrDataSize/Int16.bitWidth
        let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start: buffPtrInt16,
                                                        count: unsafePtrByteSize)

        // Average of each sample squared, then root squared
        let sumOfSquaredSamples = samples.map(Float.init).reduce(0) { $0 + $1*$1 }
        let averageOfSomething = sqrt(sumOfSquaredSamples / Float(samples.count))

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("Calulcus of something: \(String(averageOfSomething))" )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've played with your example. This is a full working swift 2 code snippet:

```
// also define a variable in class scope, otherwise captureOutput will not be called
    var session : AVCaptureSession!



    func startCapture() {
    if let device : AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio){

        do {
            self.session = AVCaptureSession()
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            device.unlockForConfiguration()

            if(self.session.canAddInput(audioInput)){
                self.session.addInput(audioInput)
                print("added input")
            }


            let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()

            audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0))

            if(self.session.canAddOutput(audioOutput)){
                self.session.addOutput(audioOutput)
                print("added output")
            }


            //supposed to start session not on UI queue coz it takes a while
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                print("starting captureSession")
                self.session.startRunning()
            }

        } catch {

        }
    }
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, let didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    var buffer: CMBlockBuffer? = nil

    // Needs to be initialized somehow, even if we take only the address
    var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList(mNumberBuffers: 1,
                                          mBuffers: AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 1, mDataByteSize: 0, mData: nil))

    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
        sampleBuffer,
        nil,
        &audioBufferList,
        sizeof(audioBufferList.dynamicType),
        nil,
        nil,
        UInt32(kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment),
        &buffer
    )

    let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(&audioBufferList)

    for buffer in abl {
        let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start: UnsafeMutablePointer(buffer.mData),
                                                        count: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)/sizeof(Int16))

        var sum:Int64 = 0

        for sample in samples {
            let s = Int64(sample)
            sum = (sum + s*s)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            print( String(sqrt(Float(sum/Int64(samples.count)))))
        }
    }
}
```