# How to record audio from the mic while appending a modified sampleBuffer image to the AVAssetWriter

Tags: swift, avcapturesession, avassetwriter, cmsamplebuffer

This is an extension to an unanswered question I had before: [AVCaptureSession is not recording audio from the mic in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394203/avcapturesession-is-not-recording-audio-from-the-mic-in-swift)

I'm very unclear how I can write both video that is being modified in real time and audio that is being recorded from the microphone. I've been searching for months and I have found nothing. What seems to set my problem apart from others is that I am getting an image buffer from sampleBuffer in the captureOutput function, turning that into an image, modifying it, and then writing it back to a AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor, instead of recording everything from the output as normal video. From here, I have no idea what to do to get audio from sampleBuffer, or if that's even the correct approach, although [I've seen others get an AudioBufferList from captureOutput.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818883/swift-3-using-avcaptureaudiodataoutput-to-analyze-audio-input)

Minimally, this is what I have in my main class:

```
class CaptureVC: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var stillImageOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()

    var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter?
    var assetWriterPixelBufferInput: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor?
    var assetWriterAudioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    var currentSampleTime: CMTime?
    var currentVideoDimensions: CMVideoDimensions?
    var videoIsRecording = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for:AVMediaType.video)
    let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInMicrophone, for: AVMediaType.audio, position: .unspecified)

    var error: NSError?
    var videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    var micInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera!)
        micInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone!)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        videoInput = nil
        micInput = nil
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }

    if error == nil &&
        captureSession!.canAddInput(videoInput) &&
        captureSession!.canAddInput(micInput){

        captureSession!.addInput(videoInput)
        captureSession!.addInput(micInput)

        stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()


        if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput!) {
            captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput!)

            let q = DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer delegate", qos: .default)

            videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: q)

            if captureSession!.canAddOutput(videoOutput){
                captureSession!.addOutput(videoOutput)
            }

            audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self as? AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, queue: q)

            if captureSession!.canAddOutput(audioOutput){
                captureSession!.addOutput(audioOutput)
            }

            captureSession!.startRunning()

        }

    }

}
```

My class that creates the asset writer

```
func createWriter() {
    self.checkForAndDeleteFile()

    do {
        assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: movieURL() as URL, fileType: AVFileType.mov)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let videoSettings = [
        AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
        AVVideoWidthKey : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.height), // note: these are swapped because of REASONS
        AVVideoHeightKey : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.width)
    ] as [String : Any]

    let assetWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: videoSettings)
    assetWriterVideoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

    let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [
        String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey) : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
        String(kCVPixelBufferWidthKey) : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.width),
        String(kCVPixelBufferHeightKey) : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.height),
        String(kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility) : kCFBooleanTrue
        ] as [String : Any]

    assetWriterPixelBufferInput = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: assetWriterVideoInput,
                                                                       sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)


    var channelLayout = AudioChannelLayout()
    memset(&channelLayout, 0, MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayout>.size);
    channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;

    let audioSettings: [String: Any] = [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
                                        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2]

    assetWriterAudioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
    assetWriterAudioInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

    if assetWriter!.canAdd(assetWriterVideoInput) {
        assetWriter!.add(assetWriterVideoInput)
    } else {
        print("cannot add \(assetWriterVideoInput)")
    }

    if assetWriter!.canAdd(assetWriterAudioInput!) {
        assetWriter!.add(assetWriterAudioInput!)
    } else {
        print("cannot add \(String(describing: assetWriterAudioInput))")
    }

}
```

When I record I create the writer, start writing and start the session:

```
        videoIsRecording = true

        createWriter()
        assetWriter?.startWriting()
        assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: currentSampleTime!)
```

When I stop the recording, it goes to another view to display the video:

```
        assetWriter?.finishWriting(completionHandler: {[unowned self] () -> Void in

            let firstAsset = AVURLAsset(url: self.movieURL() as URL)

            guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: firstAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }



            guard let vidComp = self.getVideoComposition(asset: firstAsset,
                                                         videoSize: CGSize(width:1280,
                                                                           height:720)) else {
                print("Unable to create video composition")
                return
            }
            print(vidComp.instructions)
            exporter.videoComposition = vidComp
            exporter.outputURL = self.movieURL() as URL
            exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov

            exporter.exportAsynchronously() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(){

                    self.activityTextStatus.text = ""

                    fileURLSenderVal = self.movieURL() as URL

                    let manageCaptureVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ManageCaptureVC") as! ManageCaptureVC

                    manageCaptureVC.fileURL = fileURLSenderVal
                    manageCaptureVC.imageCaptureMode = ManageCaptureVC.imageCaptureModes(rawValue: self.imageCaptureMode.rawValue)!
                    manageCaptureVC.delegate = self

                    self.present(manageCaptureVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
            }


        })
```

But this is where I'm stuck - where and how do I record my microphone's input??

```
// live output from camera
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection){

    if(captureOutput){

        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

        var orientation = UIImageOrientation.right

        if(isFrontCamera){

            orientation = UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored

        }


        image = UIImage(ciImage: cameraImage)

        if let ciImage = image?.ciImage {

            image = applyFilterAndReturnImage(ciImage: ciImage, orientation: orientation, currentCameraRes:currentCameraRes!)

            let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)!
            self.currentVideoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDescription)
            self.currentSampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)

            if(videoIsRecording && self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true){

                let filteredBuffer = buffer(from: image!)

                let success = self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.append(filteredBuffer!, withPresentationTime: self.currentSampleTime!)



                if success == false {
                    print("Pixel Buffer failed")
                }

            }


        DispatchQueue.main.async(){
            imageView!.image = image
        }

    }

}
```

Again, I've been at this on and off for months - No documents I can find help. Thank you

Comment: I'm currently having a similar problem. Were You able to solve it? @Chewie The Chorkie

Comment: I have a similar problem and I've found that GPUImage2 does achieve this https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2 .  Im currently digging through GPUimage and it looks like this could be a threading issue.